# Input validation within function

Tags: python, input

I'm writing a questionaire that will require thee user to input valid input. 
As per below, I'm trying to get the user to input a number and return the continent of the corresponding numbe. Any letter, string or number less than 1 or greater than 7 are invalid and will prompt the user to input again.

```
def continent_question() :
    continent = {'0': None, 1: 'asia', 2: 'africa',
                3: 'north america', 4: 'south america',
                5: 'europe', 6: 'oceania', 7: 'antarctica'}
    print('Which continent would you like to travel to?')
    print('  1)', continent[1].title())
    print('  2)', continent[2].title())
    print('  3)', continent[3].title())
    print('  4)', continent[4].title())
    print('  5)', continent[5].title())
    print('  6)', continent[6].title())
    print('  7)', continent[7].title())
    continent_input = int(input('> '))
    while True:
        try:
            continent_input = int(input('> '))
        except ValueError:
            print('I\'m, sorry,')
            continue
        if (continent_input < 1) or (continent_input > 7):
            print('Which continent would you like to travel to?')
            break
    return continent[continent_input]
```

Comment: Your code looks good. Did you have a specific question/issue in mind? :-)

Comment: It is not giving me the desired outcome. E.g when the user inputs 'a', the code crashes.

Comment: Remove the first `continent_input = int(input('> '))`.

Comment: My question is how do I manipulate the while True, execept ValueError etc so that when the user input anything other than 1 to 7, the function will ask the user to input again and again.

Comment: My answer does exactly that. You have to test for outside the int range and also whether they input an int at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your while loop doesn't break with correct input. Separating this into two functions makes it easier:

```
def get_cq(msg):
    while True:
        try:
            d = int(input(msg))
            if 1 <= d <= 7:
                return d
            else:
                print('Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 7.')
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 7.')



def continent_question():
    continent = {'0': None, 1: 'asia', 2: 'africa',
                3: 'north america', 4: 'south america',
                5: 'europe', 6: 'oceania', 7: 'antarctica'}
    print('Which continent would you like to travel to?')
    print('  1)', continent[1].title())
    print('  2)', continent[2].title())
    print('  3)', continent[3].title())
    print('  4)', continent[4].title())
    print('  5)', continent[5].title())
    print('  6)', continent[6].title())
    print('  7)', continent[7].title())
    continent_input = get_cq('Which continent would you like to travel to? ')

    return continent[continent_input]

x = continent_question()
print('Your answer is', x)
```

Edit: to answer your question, I've always done input checking with a separate function, because I find it messy without one. Remember, you can define one function within another, like so:

```
def continent_question():

    def get_cq(msg):
        while True:
            try:
                d = int(input(msg))
                if 1 <= d <= 7:
                    return d
                else:
                    print('Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 7.')
            except ValueError:
                print('Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 7.')

    continent = {'0': None, 1: 'asia', 2: 'africa',
                3: 'north america', 4: 'south america',
                5: 'europe', 6: 'oceania', 7: 'antarctica'}
    print('Which continent would you like to travel to?')
    print('  1)', continent[1].title())
    print('  2)', continent[2].title())
    print('  3)', continent[3].title())
    print('  4)', continent[4].title())
    print('  5)', continent[5].title())
    print('  6)', continent[6].title())
    print('  7)', continent[7].title())
    continent_input = get_cq('Which continent would you like to travel to? ')

    return continent[continent_input]

x = continent_question()
print('Your answer is', x)
```

so as not to clutter the rest of your code.

2nd question:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55311752/input-validation-within-function/55311826#55311826

def continent_question():

    def get_cq(msg):
        while True:
            try:
                d = input(msg)
                if 1 <= int(d) <= 7:
                    return int(d)
                else:
                    print(f'\'{d}\' is an invalid input. Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 7. Your Options:')
                    print('  1)', continent[1].title())
                    print('  2)', continent[2].title())
                    print('  3)', continent[3].title())
                    print('  4)', continent[4].title())
                    print('  5)', continent[5].title())
                    print('  6)', continent[6].title())
                    print('  7)', continent[7].title())
            except ValueError:
                print(f'\'{d}\' is an invalid input. Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 7. Your Options:')
                print('  1)', continent[1].title())
                print('  2)', continent[2].title())
                print('  3)', continent[3].title())
                print('  4)', continent[4].title())
                print('  5)', continent[5].title())
                print('  6)', continent[6].title())
                print('  7)', continent[7].title())

    continent = {'0': None, 1: 'asia', 2: 'africa',
                3: 'north america', 4: 'south america',
                5: 'europe', 6: 'oceania', 7: 'antarctica'}
    print('Which continent would you like to travel to?')
    print('  1)', continent[1].title())
    print('  2)', continent[2].title())
    print('  3)', continent[3].title())
    print('  4)', continent[4].title())
    print('  5)', continent[5].title())
    print('  6)', continent[6].title())
    print('  7)', continent[7].title())
    continent_input = get_cq('Which continent would you like to travel to? ')

    return continent[continent_input]

x = continent_question()
print('Your answer is', x)
```

Comment: Hi Alec, thank you so muhc, that works great. If I may ask, are there ways which we dont need to write a second function? eg keeping it all in continent_question()? This is just one of the questions/functions I have, so if i need to add an extra function for every question, its quite messy.

Comment: I edited my post with a neater way to do it. If my answer was helpful, would you mind upvoting and accepting? The latter grants you reputation :)

Comment: No problem :) For the sake of transparency, it might be a good idea to vary the output between `ValueError` and a simple out-of-range. For example, the former could say "please enter an integer" and the latter could say "Out of range: 1-7 are the only valid inputs"

Comment: Hey Alec, if the message was to include the user input, eg user input 'three', the mesaage is to read ' three is not a valid choice'. If thats the case, which variable do i need to call in the message?

Comment: `d` stores the value they entered as long as it was an integer. If you want `d` to store anything they enter (like 'sup bro'), you'll have to let d be anything and then cast it as an int in the equality conditional and return `int(d)`. a `ValueError` will still be raised if it can't be cast into an `int` so doing this won't break anything.

Comment: Great, that worked, now when the user input anything but the code would ask then to re-input. What if I need the code to print out the question again when the wrong input was used? Do i just call continent_question function?(that didnt work)

Comment: I edited my post with the correct way to do it. Nothing needs to be changed except the casting.

Comment: Yes, I have made the same changes too. I meant is there a way to print out the question and choices again when the user input anything but the right integer.

Comment: The easiest way would just be to put the options in that print statement. 9 separate ones, like you already have, is much nicer than many \n’s

Comment: Given that it's now repeated 3x, it'd make the code nicer just to define a `print_options()` function